# How IDM fetches download links from sites like Youtube?

Tags: javascript, java, web-applications, google-chrome-extension, desktop-application

I'm developing chrome extension for my Java based download manager.How do i listen to browser download events?And how do download managers fetch links from site's like YouTube where direct video links are not present in the source file?

Comment: They install a chrome extension that communicates with the external downloader via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: That's what i want to know.How to implement that ?Any helpful resource link?

Comment: You can look at a [sample extension that uses chrome.downloads API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:downloads) and inspect the code of the extension installed by those downloaders.

Answer (score 2):

I am also building a similar kind of application for learning purpose.
Well, there are multiple ways to do it. One way is to use chrome's native messaging API. This API can send messages from your extension to your desktop application.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging-host

The other way would be to embed a small server in your desktop application. So, when the user installs the application the server is automatically deployed and listens for a connection.

Once you have your server ready you can send http requests from your extension. To do this your extension can open a connection and send a POST REQUEST to an address (e.g. 127.0.0.1:9690). When the request is sent successfully, the desktop application scans the url and depending upon the url the application uses certain algorithm to download the file.

For eg: if the url is of youtube, you use certain techniques to parse the url and get the approprite audio or video.

Comment: I was able to communicate with my desktop application but what i want to know is how to override the chrome's default download manager like IDM do for downloading.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is disable idm extension by your extension. If that is so then i don't think it will be possible. It might be possible if you write some malicious script that somehow searches for idm and breaks it but it should be tough. This will also be a security risk.

What you can do is tell the user to disable IDM extension. 

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management